# Generate a stub or mocking a method in .NET

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, stub

I am writing a unit test that performs logic as the following:

```
SomeObject obj1 = new SomeObject();
obj1.SomeMethod(args);
```

Inside `SomeMethod`:

```
public void SomeMethod(*Some Args*){     
    AnotherObject obj2 = new AnotherObject();
    Obj2.OtherMethod();
}
```

In my testing I dont care about what Obj2.OtherMethod() really does, and I want the testing to overlook it. So I think generating a stub will fix it for me, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at Moq or RhinoMocks?  It sounds like you want to mock the Obj2.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach.  If you had an interface which AnotherObject implemented (say IAnother, which as a minimum has AnotherMethod as a method), your normal execution path would pass in an instance of AnotherObject to SomeMethod.

Then for testing, you could pass a mock object which implements the IAnother interface - either by using a mock framework or coding one yourself.

So you'd have:

```
Public void SomeMethod(IAnother anotherObject)
{     
  anotherObbject.OtherMethod();
}
```

and

```
Public class MyMock : IAnother...
```

for testing -

```
IAnother another = new MyMock();
..SomeMethod(myMock)
```

but in the real code

```
IAnother = new AnotherObject()...
```

you get the idea.